# Android - openFileInput() NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, io, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to generate a code as string in my android application and save it to a text file. When you press a Share button, the code should be read from the text file and be copied to the clipboard.

I guess I'm not understanding something about acivity/context.
Of course I read in the documentation about it, but I can't figure out the problem. Hope you guys could help me!

FileSystem.java

```java
package com.niclasjaksch.shoppinglist;

import android.content.Context;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

class FileSystem extends AppCompatActivity {

    static String filename = "shoppinglist_code.txt";

    void Create() {
        try {
            FileOutputStream fOut = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            String str = Utility.randomString(10);
            fOut.write(str.getBytes());
            fOut.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    String Read() {
        String result = "";
        try {
            FileInputStream fin = openFileInput(filename);
            int c;
            while( (c = fin.read()) != -1){
                result += c;
            }
            fin.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("An error occurred.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }
    void Clear() {
        try {
            File dir = getFilesDir();
            File file = new File(dir, filename);
            file.delete();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("An error occurred.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Share.java

```java
package com.niclasjaksch.shoppinglist;

import android.content.ClipData;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

class Share extends AppCompatActivity {

    android.content.ClipboardManager clipboardManager = null;
    FileSystem fs = new FileSystem();

    void Share() {
        String code = fs.Read();
        if(code == "" || code == null) {
            fs.Create();
            code = fs.Read();
        }
        ClipData clipData = ClipData.newPlainText("Source Text", code);
        clipboardManager.setPrimaryClip(clipData);
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```java
    ...

    Share share = new Share();

    ...

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.item_share:
                share.Share();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

Getting a NullPointerException in this line:

```java
FileOutputStream fOut = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Comment: Please share the logcat as well so that we can understand which variable is assigned to null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only create subclasses of `AppCompatActivity` for actual UI work, where you will start that activity using `startActivity()` or `startActivityForResult()`.

Move those methods to a real activity, such as `MainActivity`, and get rid of the `Share` and `FileSystem` classes.

Answer (score -1):

First things first, you shouldn't extend `AppCompatActivity` for `FileSystem` and `Share`.

What's happening is that the `openFileOutput` is taking the `FileSystem` object (`this`) as it's context. When in reality it wouldn't count as a separate activity.

You could either do as CommonWare suggest and remove the classes `FileSystem` and `Share`, and move their functions to the `MainActivity`. Or you could explicitly pass the `context` from the `MainActivity`.